# Humanx Commonwealth reading order?

Tags: suggested-order, humanx-commonwealth

There seem to be many different plot lines in Alan Dean Foster's *[Humanx Commonwealth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanx_Commonwealth)*.

Is it sufficient to read each series in publication order, or do I need to switch between series as I read?

Comment: Personally, I read them in publication order because, well, publication order, and I didn't have any problems with that.

Comment: Seconding publication order. Initially tried to read the Flinx portion of the series in chronological order as a youngster, and going from  "For Love of Mother-Not" to "The Tar-Ayim Krang" was jarring.

Comment: "Nor Crystal Tears" is about first contact between humans and Thranx and could be read before the others, but it isn't necessary.

Comment: @notovny that experience would be a the basis for a good answer